# Can Someone explain to me this assembly code?

Tags: assembly

I am very new to assembly language and this is basically my first go at it. I'm trying to understand how this code works like the Pre-Execution Mapped Memory and Post-Execution Mapped Memory. I know that formatting is important in assembly, I've already formatted the code in asmIDE but when I pasted it here it got messed up. Just in case you guys want to know it compiled and in debugging, I was able to get
 [image: https://db.tt/rudh5oBZ (image)]

as pre-execution with debug but I'm not sure how it works.. I need some clarity.

also can someone clarify these keywords: dw, difference between $ and no $, staa, swi,std? thanks. I'm writting this for the Dragon12 micro controller.

```
          org     $1000  ;start at ram

  Val1    dw      $1234
  Val2    db      16
  Val3    dw      1234

  Val4    equ     $06


          org     $1020

   Res0    ds      1
   Res1    ds      1
   Res2    ds      2
   Res3    ds      1
   Res4    ds      2

    org     $2000 ;start at rom

   ldaa    Val2

    staa    Res0
    ldab    #Val4
    stab    Res1
    ldd     Val3
    stab    Res2
    ldaa    $1001
    std     Res2
    staa    Val3+1
    swi

    end
```

Comment: Clarity needed indeed - start by telling us the processor you're writing for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ is a prefix that means the subsequent number is in hexadecimal form.  Otherwise, the number is in decimal form.

dw "define word" is a directive to define a two byte block of memory.  The number following the dw is the initial value of that memory when the program starts.

db "define byte" is a similar directive as dw, but specifies a single byte.

I don't know the "dragon" assembly language, but these are very common directives to many assemblers.  The actual assembly instructions are specific to the cpu though.  I could guess what staa, swi, std mean, but won't.  You should be able to look them up pretty easily.

Comment: What's the difference between  `ldab #Val4` and `ldab Val4`?

Comment: ldab #Val4 means load the number 6 (remember the Val4 is defined by equ to be a synonym for $06) into the accumulator B register.

ldab Val4 means load the content of memory at address 6 into that register.